# how to convert complex string inside a json data to an array

Tags: arrays, json

**JSON:**

```
{
    "arr":"000239@@@a;1=2.5=1;2=5.1=0#b;1=1.3=1;2=1.7=0@@@a;1=39=0;2=8.5=0#b;1=7.6=0;2=2.4=0@@@a#b"
}
```

I need the result to look like this:

```
1    a    1    2.5    1
1    a    2    5.1    0
1    b    1    1.3    1
1    b    2    1.7    0
2    a    1    39     0
2    a    2    8.5    0
2    b    1    7.7    0
2    b    2    2.4    0
```

Comment: 1) What language or platform are you using? 2) What have you tried so far? 3) What went wrong with your attempt (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Comment: Cleaned up the array to add a line break after each semi-colon, unfortunately it's still a mess.

Comment: @TravisHeeter, in your edit you made the JSON invalid: string literals cannot have real line breaks.

Comment: Thanks trincot,, do you have any idea to convert the string?!

Comment: done by using multi-string function... thanks all

Comment: @trincot I was trying to make it readable because it makes no sense. Why does it have to be strict JSON? It's just an example of the JSON right? But if it has to be strict, why don't we just put it in a template literal so people don't waste time trying to decipher this string that makes no sense anyway?

Comment: @TravisHeeter, the OP had posted *valid* JSON, mentioning that it was JSON (and that is correct), so whatever our opinion on the content of that JSON, we should not make it worse by making the JSON invalid. That in itself could raise comments like *"Your JSON is invalid!"*, which would not be helpful to the OP at all.

Comment: @trincot I see your point. However, I doubt he's going to get any help with that mess. But I guess making it more readable wouldn't really help that anyway.

Comment: Anyway, I voted to close this as "unclear".

Answer (score 0):

So your first two columns, I have no idea what you're looking for there. You need to be more specific about how those columns relate to the data you posted.

But for the rest of it, it looks like you can split around the semi-colons:

```
var newArray = arr.split(';');
```

This will give you an actual array like so:

```
["000239@@@a", "1=2.5=1", "2=5.1=0#b","1=1.3=1", "2=1.7=0@@@a", "1=39=0", "2=8.5=0#b", "1=7.6=0", "2=2.4=0@@@a#b"]
```

Then you can loop through those and get your last 3 columns:

```
var lastThreeColumns = newArray.filter( e => e.includes('=') )
    .map( e => e.split( '=' ) );
```

That will give you an array of arrays, like this:

```
[[1, 2.5, 1],[2, 5.1, "0#b"],[1, 1.3, 1]...]
```

This question will probably be closed, so be sure to spend more time writing the question next time. In my experience, it takes at least an hour to write a question that SO will be able to help you with.